# If $T: E \rightarrow E$ is a bounded linear operator, then $e^T$ is as well

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis, vector-spaces, operator-theory, uniform-convergence

On page 39 of *Differential Dynamical Systems* (revised edition) by Meiss, the author gives the following Lemma.

> **Lemma 2.8**: If $T$ is a bounded linear operator, then $e^T$ is as well.

We are assuming (I think) that $T: E \rightarrow E$, where $E$ is a normed vector space over $\mathbb{R}$. I have a couple doubts about the proof of the lemma, which goes as follows:

> **Proof**: Choose an arbitrary $x \in E$ and consider the value of $e^T(x)$. By definition (2.25) [$e^T \equiv \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{T^k}{k!}$], this is a series whose terms are elements of $E$. The norm of this series is bounded by the sum of the norms of each term. By the definition of the operator norm, for any $x$,
> $$ |T(x)| \leq \|T\| |x|, $$
> $$ |T^k(x)|  = |T(T^{k-1}(x))| \leq \|T\| |T^{k-1}(x)| \leq \cdots \leq \|T\|^k |x|. $$

> Consequently, each of the terms in the series $e^T(x)$ can be bounded by
> $$ \left|\frac{T^k(x)}{k!} \right| \leq \frac{\|T\|^k}{k!} |x| = M_k. $$

> The series of real numbers
> $$ \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} M_k = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{\|T\|^k}{k!}|x| = e^{\|T\|}|x| $$
> converges for any finite value of $\|T\|$. By the Weierstrass M-test $|e^T(x)| \leq e^{\|T\|}|x|$ and the series for $e^T(x)$ converges uniformly in $x$. Moreover, $\|e^T\| \leq e^{\|T\|}$, so the exponential is a bounded operator. $\qquad \square$

My questions:

1. How are we allowed to use the Weierstrass M-test here? Don't we require that the norm of each term in the series is bounded *uniformly* in $x$, i.e. $\left|\frac{T^k(x)}{k!}\right| \leq M_k$ for **all** $x \in E$?  (I am going by the version of the Weierstrass M-Test that I stated in this [previous post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4509887/proof-verification-weierstrass-m-test-for-f-k-k-1-infty-f-k-x-to).
2. Don't we also need to assume that $E$ is a Banach-space? (This was an assumption I used in the proof I linked.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You certainly need to assume $E$ is a Banach space, else you'd have to make the rather odd assertion: "$e^T$ exists for all $T$", and I think most mathematicians would only ever work with such an assertion in the wider context of a Banach space.

As for the $M$-test, you can be satisfied with showing that $e^T(x)$ converges *locally uniformly*. I expect this is what the author meant, as it can be strengthened to "uniform convergence over bounded subsets", which is strong enough for a lot of purposes. For example, you might fix a radius $R$ and use the $M$-test on the set $B_R(0)$, which is sufficient to get continuity and boundedness with $\|e^T\|\le e^{\|T\|}$ by bounding $|x|\le R$.

It is not true even in $E=\Bbb R$ that $e^x$ converges uniformly over the *whole* space. Rather we have uniform convergence over any bounded subset.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! That makes a lot of sense. And $e^x$ is a good counterexample for non-uniform convergence (over the whole space).

Answer (score 1):

Yes we do need to assume that $E$ is a Banach space so that $L(E)$ is also a Banach space. The sum $e^T = \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!}T^n$ converges absolutely in the Banach space $L(E)$ since $\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!}\|T^n\| \leq \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!}\|T\|^n = e^{\|T\|} < \infty$. In particular, the sum converges in $L(E)$-norm.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So if I understand correctly, you are using the fact that if $L(E)$ is complete then every absolutely convergent series in $L(E)$ is convergent. Then I agree that $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n!} \|T^n\|$ converges in the operator norm, i.e. $ \lim_{n \to \infty} \sup \left\{ \|T_n(x) - T(x) \|_{E}: \|x\|_E = 1 \right\} = 0$, but this is not the same as *uniform* convergence on $E$, which would mean that $ \lim_{n \to \infty}  \sup \left\{ \|T_n(x) - T(x) \|_{E}: x \in E \right\} = 0$. Do I have that right?

Comment: @Leonidas Correct, convergence in operator norm does not imply uniform convergence. However, it implies uniform convergence on any ball $B_{R}(0)$, so it implies locally uniform convergence.

Comment: Got it, thanks for clarifying.